# Get previous console output as string in script

Tags: python

I have a script that returns an output in the console, eg (not the actual code just an example):

```
print("Hello World")
```

I want to be able to catch this output as a string and store it as a variable:

```
print("Hello World")

# function to catch previous line output and store it as a variable
```

Comment: `a = "Hello World"` `print(a)`

Comment: Assign it to a var?

Comment: the code I provided is an illustration and not the actuall code. Of course this is easier but it doesn't meet the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by the wording in your question that you are running the first print command in a different script than the first one. In that case you can run it using the subprocess module and catch the output like this:

```py
from subprocess import run

result = run(['script.py'], capture_output=True)
previous_output = result.stdout
```

Comment: not that is not the case, this is all contained in a single script.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do that

```
a = "Hello World !"
print(a)
```

it's easier than trying to capture it after printing the actual string, but if you insist,
@Blupper already answered your question.

Comment: the code I provided is an illustration and not the actuall code. Of course this is easier but it doesn't meet the functionality I'm looking for.